# NativeScript - How to get the caret position of TextView in iOS

Tags: ios, textview, nativescript, caret

I'm using NativeScript-Vue and I'm having a problem finding out the caret position of `TextView` in iOS

```
<StackLayout>
    <TextView ref="input" editable=true @loaded="getView"/>
</StackLayout>

...

getView(args) {
    console.log(args.object.ios)      // return {}
    console.log(this.$refs.input.ios) // return {}
}

...
```

https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/getting-cursor-position-of-textview-in-ios/5931

I have read the solution above but it seems like only support TypeScript?

What I get from the `this.$refs.input.nativeView.ios` is always `{}` (empty)

Does anyone know what I missed? Or any available approach is welcome! Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `this.$refs.input.nativeView.ios` only, it may print empty object as it's a native component.

Comment: Thanks for replying but sorry @Manoj, I don't really get what you mean, so how can I get the `beginningOfDocument`? I did `console.log(this.$refs.input.nativeView.ios.beginningOfDocument` and also return an empty obj, is it normal as it's a native component?

Comment: You can only dump all available properties or methods of a JavaScript object in console, native objects can't be treated the same way it is going to return only empty object but should still work. Here is a working sample - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=q1LnDV If you use TypeScript, you may utilise `tns-platform-declrations` package that will help you list all available native methods on native objects.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function that allows me to get the selected text. From this function you could also determine where your caret position is.

```
function getSelectedText(view) {
  let selection = {
    start: view.ios.selectedRange.location,
    end: view.ios.selectedRange.location + view.ios.selectedRange.length,
    length: view.ios.selectedRange.length
  }
  
  return selection;
}
```

To use this function just get the refrence of your textfield:

```
getSelectedText(this.$refs.textField.nativeView);
```